# Is it possible to iterate over the same number twice

Tags: python, for-loop

Essentially my code looks like this

```
for i in range(10):
 print(i)
 if i == 8:
  i -=1
```

That code prints 0 through 10 as normal instead of printing 8 twice. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: Use a while loop instead, and manually increment the index. You can't achieve what you want using for..range construct

Comment: Not sure why you would do something like this because you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Also you said your code prints 0 through 10 but it doesn't, and shouldn't. It will print 0 through 9

Comment: @BramVanroy That would happen in a loop where i is a variable defined outside. With for i in range, the number of iteration is limited to the number of values provided by the iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this custom generator:

```
def same_number_iterator(last, same_number_twice):
    i = 0
    while i < last:
        yield i
        if i in same_number_twice:
            yield i
        i += 1

for i in same_number_iterator(10, same_number_twice=[8]):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
8
9
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Aviv works for the problem you described. However, since the title says "Is it possible to iterate over the same number twice?" maybe what you want to know is how to repeat a certain iteration given a condition. If that's the case, you could simply do this:

```
repeated = False
i = 0
while i<10:
    print(i)
    if i == 8 and not repeated:
        repeated = True
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: I think the other answer is better all around but I ended up using something like this to solve my problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing that you can do is have an inner `for` loop, that does either 1 or 2 iterations depending on the value of `i`.

```
for i in range(10):
    for _ in range(2 if i == 8 else 1):
        print(i)
```